# Drupal8 How to set a logo?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

i am new to drupal. I installed drupal 8 then tried to learn it. I wanted to change the logo of my site. i am using theme Bartik. I went to apperance settings->logo image settings->upload logo image. I selected an image and tried to save the configuration i get a error like this.

```
Fatal error: Cannot instantiate interface Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface in /home/user/public_html/dp8/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php on line 265
```

why am i getting this fatal error? Which did i miss?

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused because of any contributed module you added. I had changed the logo on my system and it works fine, try to clear caches and disable and dev version modules.

Regards